# Probability density function of $W = X + Y$ where $X \sim \mathrm{Unif}[0,1]$ and $Y \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ are independent random variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

This is the question that I was given:

[image: Question]

And this was the provided solution:

[image: Solution]

I can't seem to make sense of it - firstly, what exactly is the question asking you to do? How did they know to divide the range of $w$ in that way? And why did they use those particular limits for the integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ can take values in $[0,1]$, and $Y$ in $[0,\infty)$, and so $W=X+Y$ can take values in $[0,\infty)$.  But if $W<1$, then there are limitations on the value that $X$ can take.  For example, if $W=0.5$, how could $X>0.5$ when $Y$ cannot be less than zero?  This is precisely what Case 1 is saying: when $W<1$, then $X<W$ as well.  But if $W>1$, then all values of $X$ in its range $[0,1]$ are permissible.  So the convolution is taken by integrating over the permissible ranges of $X$ as defined by the cases.  Finally, the question is asking you to find the complete density function, which can only be found in cases conditioned on the value of $W$.

Comment: A very clear explanation, thank you.

Comment: @Mathlete: You're welcome!  I don't know where you are in your studies, but the kind of thinking in this problem is key once you begin *conditional probability*, which is really where probability becomes interesting and useful.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that both random values $X$ and $Y$ yield only positive values. Thus, $X+Y = w$ requires that $X$ yields a value $\geq w$, because otherwise the sum will surely be larger than $w$.

Note though that the convolution formula deals with that correctly - you just have to be carefull when computing the integral. Let $$
  f_W(w) = \int_0^1 f_X(x)f_Y(w-x) \,dx  \text{.}
$$
unconditionally. Then watch what happens if you evaluate $f_W(\omega)$ with $\omega < 1$. Once $x$ reaches $\omega$, $\omega-x$ becomes zero, and negative afterwards. You thus evaluate $f_Y$ for negative arguments, where its simply zero. But if you aren't carefull, you might have simply replaced $f_Y(w-x)$ with $\lambda e^{-\lambda(w-x)}$, and *that* function *isn't* zero for $x > w$!

So all that happens here is that your densities are defined *piecewise*, i.e. for different ranges of arguments they're represented by different algebraic expressions. When computing the integral, you have to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

A tip: draw a plot of $X$ against $Y$ to find the domain of $W$. Then you will find that you cannot do the integration with only one integral; you need to divide it into two. Since $Y=W-X$, it looks like this:

[image: plot]

As you can see, there is a triangle and then an infinite rectangle. The situation is different depending on which one you are considering. The rationale is this: you know that $y \in [0, \infty)$ and that $x\in[0, 1]$. Hence, $w\in[0, \infty)$. Thus, the limits are:

$$
0<x<w, \quad \text{for } w<1\\
0<x<1, \quad \text{for } w>1
$$

Say that $w=0.6$. Then, obviously, $x$ cannot be 0.7 for example. If $w=14$, then $x$ can be anything in its support, that is on the interval 0 to 1.